# Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, swap, systemctl, hibernate

I'm trying to hibernate via `systemctl hibernate` but get `Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation`

```
LANG=C swapon

NAME           TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swap/swapfile file 200G   0B   -2

##################################

LANG=C free -h

               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31Gi       7.3Gi        12Gi       2.2Gi        11Gi        21Gi
Swap:          199Gi          0B       199Gi

##################################

cat /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=22dffee9-9be9-4ab3-afe3-ef0ac025c1c3 resume_offset=173273088 quiet splash"
```

Seems everything is fine and I have much more then required swap space, but why systemctl disinformates me?

UPD 1:

```
systemctl hibernate

dmesg
PM: Cannot find swap device, try swapon -a
PM: Cannot get swap write
```

Comment: Probably a bug.

Comment: Is your swapfile contiguous? How did you create it? `dd` will create fragmented swap. The kernel wants to write one big all-of-RAM blob onto ONE chunk of disk, and restore one blob on the other side. Check with `test`'s `-C` option, if your `test` supports `-C`. See `man test`.

Comment: Unfortunately my test doesn;t support `test  -C`.

Comment: filefrag -X swapfile 

swapfile: 3 extents found

Comment: PM: Cannot find swap device, try swapon -a; PM: Cannot get swap write